# PHP SQL select from multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, fetch

i'm having a problem with a code i've written to fetch data from 3 tables, its a tourism website, and i would like the user to search across three tables :

- hotel [HNo,Name,Description,Location,Address,Price]
- resturant [RNo,Name,Description,Location,Address,Price]
- parks [ParkNo,Location,Description,Address]

my select statement is as follows :

```
SELECT hotel.HNo
      ,hotel.Name
      ,hotel.Description
      ,hotel.Location
      ,hotel.Address
      ,hotel.Price
      ,restaurant.RNo
      ,restaurant.Name
      ,restaurant.Description
      ,restaurant.Location
      ,restaurant.Address
      ,restaurant.Price
      ,parks.ParkNo
      ,parks.Location
      ,parks.Description
      ,parks.Address
FROM hotel, restaurant, parks 
WHERE hotel.Name LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
   OR parks.Location LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
   OR restaurant.Name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
```

Now the problem is, after fetching the data using `while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))`
I'm not able to identify whether i'm printing data from hotel, restaurant or parks table, its necessary since parks don't have names, and user can make a reservation if its a hotel.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign aliases to columns in your `SELECT` clause to give them distinct names in your result.

E.g.

```
SELECT hotel.HNo, hotel.Name AS hotelName, hotel.Description AS hotelDesc, hotel.Location AS hotelLocation
```

and then you refer to these aliases when working with the rows contained in your query result.
E.g.

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   echo $data['hotelName']; 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i use this alias to print out the result, do i use $data['alias'] ?

Comment: Fair question, I extended my answer to address this.